# Copy Animation to another rig

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I have two armatures with the same exact bone names and one of them is animated and the other is not, I wonder how I can copy the animation from one to the other?
I've tried answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36774/copy-animation-from-rig-to-rig) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53656/animation-transfer-from-one-rig-to-another)
but once I assign the original action to the target armature the armature moves as one piece and in different location.

I wonder how I can copy the animation from the Source armature to the Target armature and also where the target armature will be on top of the source armature (same location).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to assign the "source" action to the target armature via the dopesheet, but there are 3 main problems in your attempt:

1) The scale of the two armatures are different (Source: 0.094, Target: 1)

2) The animation of source is expressed in hips location and all bones Euler rotation, while all target bones are on quaternion: you will have to select every bone in pose mode and switch it to euler rotation mode in the "N" panel; by now the target reads only hips location, every other animation information is lost.

3) The bone's location and roll angle are so different from source to target that I think is nearly impossible to make this animation work on the target rig (on this last point, maybe someone more expert than me has a solution)